# Select Menu for Custom post Type does not save

Tags: custom-post-types, php, custom-field, select, customization

I posted a discussion on CSS-Tricks the other day. Explaining that my Videos were not displaying on my Video page from my custom post type that I created using this tutorial. I thought I fixed the issue but it turns out the issue wasn't resolved.

Anyway, so I thought maybe the way I setup my CPT/Fields were messing things up. So I found another tutorial and redid the CPT and Fields, [here is the new code.](http://pastebin.com/qxvYgit4)

I was able to get my Video ID field to save, but when I select "Youtube" or "Vimeo", then save, it just goes back to it's default option "Select". So when I view my page the container where the video should be placed is blank.

I am new to all of this Wordpress PHP so I have no idea if the select menu code is correct...or whatever the issue is.
I'd appreciate any help to find the cause of this.

**EDIT//**
After editing this line:

```
$ret .= '<script>jQuery(document).ready(function(){ jQuery("#videotype").val(' . get_video_field("videotype") . ') });</script></div>';
```

to this:

```
$ret .= '<script>jQuery(document).ready(function(){ jQuery("#videotype").val("' . get_video_field("videotype") . '") });</script></div>';
```

The Selected Video Type can now be saved, but my issue with a blank container remains...
I pasted the PHP section which should display the video in [this pastebin.](http://pastebin.com/hb3YmZSM)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a javascript issue. on line 52:

```
$ret .= '<script>jQuery(document).ready(function(){ jQuery("#videotype").val(' . get_video_field("videotype") . ') });</script></div>';
```

In this specific bit:

```
.val(' . get_video_field("videotype") . ')
```

The value isn't quoted, so it's trying to reference a variable named `youtube` or `vimeo`, which doesn't exist, instead of a literal text value.

If you add quotes it'll work, note the addition of double quotes before and after the single quotes:

```
.val("' . get_video_field("videotype") . '")
```

So the whole line will be:

```
$ret .= '<script>jQuery(document).ready(function(){ jQuery("#videotype").val("' . get_video_field("videotype") . '") });</script></div>';
```

**EDIT-**
In your template, these two lines:

```
$videotype = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Video Type', single);
$videoid = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Video ID', single);
```

Should be:

```
$videotype = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'videotype', true);
$videoid = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'videoid', true);
```

Comment: Thank you for your time, and for explaining the issue. I tried adding the line, and now the selected video type gets saved but on the front-end my video still doesn't appear...I have a feeling the issue might be in the php code within my video's template. I will edit my question and add the php into a pastebin...if you don't mind looking through it?

Comment: see edit above.